# Java Multi threading

Tags: java, multithreading

I have to use two threads such that one thread prints all the odd numbers less than 10, and the other to print even numbers less than 10 and the final output should be in sequence.

I have achieved this as follows. I want to do the same using synchronized methods? How to do it?

```
class printodd extends Thread{

public void run() {

    super.run();
    for(int i=0;i<10;i=i+2){
        System.out.println("even "+i);
    try {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }
 }
} 
class printeven extends Thread{
public void run() {

    super.run();
    for(int i=1;i<10;i=i+2)
    {
        System.out.println("odd "+i);
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1050);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
}
public class PrintNumSeq{
public static void main(String[] args) {
    printodd p=new printodd();
    printeven e=new printeven();
    e.start();
    p.start();
}
}
```

Comment: what do you mean synchronized methods? they are two independent threads printing, why do you need synchronization?

Comment: it's ok even if the threads of the same object are printing but I want the threads to take turns and print the numbers in sequence of 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 ... is there any other way to achieve this? @greedybuddha

Comment: You will want to use a common boolean variable between the two classes.  Then while it's not the right turn you will `wait`.  When you are finished you will `notify`

Comment: By the way, your code will fail for large maximums (e.g., print all even/odd numbers less than 10000) because of your `sleep(1000)` and `sleep(1050)`. It would probably be better to have the `PrintEven` thread `sleep(50)` *outside* of the loop, then use `sleep(1000)` inside, so that they have the same frequency but are out of phase.

Comment: Sounds like a homework question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
public class PrintNumSeq extends Thread {
    static Object lock = new Object();
    static int n;
    int even;

    PrintNumSeq(int r) {
        this.even = r;
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            synchronized (lock) {
                for (;;) {
                    while ((n & 1) != even) {
                        lock.wait();
                    }
                    n++;
                    lock.notify();
                    if (n > 10) {
                        break;
                    }
                    System.out.println(n);
                }
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new PrintNumSeq(1).start();
        new PrintNumSeq(0).start();
    }
}
```

output

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

Comment: Thanks..., ;-) btw this was asked in one of the interviews .., sounded interesting, hence I posted it over here.., :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
public class SequentialThreadPrinter {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger(0);
        EvenThread even = new EvenThread("even", counter);
        OddThread odd = new OddThread("odd", counter);
        even.start();
        odd.start();
    }
}

private static class EvenThread extends Thread {
    private String name;
    private AtomicInteger counter;

    public EvenThread(String name, AtomicInteger counter) {
        this.name = name;
        this.counter = counter;
    }

    public void run() {
        do {
            synchronized (counter) {
                if (counter.get() % 2 == 0) {
                    System.out.println("Thread is " + name + ", Counter is = " + counter.getAndAdd(1));
                    counter.notifyAll();
                } else {
                    try {
                        counter.wait();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        } while (counter.get() <= 10);
    }
}

private static class OddThread extends Thread {
    private String name;
    private AtomicInteger counter;

    public OddThread(String name, AtomicInteger counter) {
        this.name = name;
        this.counter = counter;
    }

    public void run() {
        do {
            synchronized (counter) {
                if (counter.get() % 2 != 0) {
                    System.out.println("Thread is " + name + ", Counter is = " + counter.getAndAdd(1));
                    counter.notifyAll();
                } else {
                    try {
                        counter.wait();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        } while (counter.get() <= 10);
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score -1):

Hi in here you have to use java synchronization. Basically synchronization is Java mechanism shared between thread which will block all other threads while one is running. By doing so in your case you can print them sequentially.
You can read the following tutorial to understand it

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/syncmeth.html
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/locksync.html

Be careful though while you use it, because not using carefully might create a deadlock
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/deadlock.html

Answer (score -2):

You could achieve this by having the threads acquire a common lock in order to be allowed to print anything.

The "lock" could be some singleton like:

```
public class Lock {

private static Lock instance;
private static boolean inUse = false;

public static Lock getInstance() {
    if(instance == null) {
        instance = new Lock();
    }
    return instance;
}

public boolean acquireLock() {
    boolean rv = false;
    if(inUse == false) {
        inUse = true;
        rv = true;
    }
    return rv;
}

public void releaseLock() {
    inUse = false;
}

}
```

Whenever a thread wants to print it has to call `acquireLock()` and if it returns true, then it can print. If it returns false, then it has to wait until it returns true. Immediately after printing the thread calls `releaseLock()` so that the Lock is freed.

I didn't test this code, so use it at your own risk. I just typed it up really quick as it was the idea I was thinking of.

You can read more about locks and their use in synchronization here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lock_(computer_science)

Comment: Acquiring the lock isn't thread-safe. Just instantiate it eagerly.